# I am trying to create a mysql trigger, but not able to, dont know what the error is

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

This is trigger query

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER adjust_ref_token
AFTER INSERT
    ON transactions FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE token_ref integer;

SELECT ico_stages.sales_token INTO @token_ref WHERE ico_stages.start_date <= NOW() <= ico_stages.end_date;

IF NEW.tnx_type = 'referral' THEN
    UPDATE ico_stages SET ico_stages.sales_token = (@token_ref - NEW.tokens) WHERE ico_stages.start_date <= NOW() <= ico_stages.end_date;
END IF;
END $$
```

Error showing is

```
    CREATE TRIGGER adjust_ref_token
AFTER INSERT
    ON transactions FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE token_ref integer;

SELECT ico_stages.sales_token INTO @token_ref WHERE ico_stages.start_date <= NOW() <= ico_stages.end_date;

IF NEW.tnx_type = 'referral' THEN
    UPDATE ico_stages SET ico_stages.sales_token = (@token_ref - NEW.tokens) WHERE ico_stages.start_date <= NOW() <= ico_stages.end_date;
END IF;
END
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE token_ref integer;
>
> SELECT ico_stages.sales_token INTO @token_ref WHER' at line 4

Can anyone please tell me whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER adjust_ref_token AFTER INSERT ON transactions
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE token_ref integer;

    SELECT ico_stages.sales_token INTO @token_ref WHERE ico_stages.start_date <= NOW() <= ico_stages.end_date;

    IF NEW.tnx_type = 'referral' THEN 
        UPDATE ico_stages SET ico_stages.sales_token = (@token_ref - NEW.tokens) WHERE ico_stages.start_date <= NOW() <= ico_stages.end_date; 
    END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Basically if you want to execute multiple statements within the trigger, you have to use `BEGIN...END` construct.
For more details https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html